# Switch not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

This is my first question here, please don't get mad if it's stupid...
So I've got this block of code, and it isn't working:

```
var clicks = 0;

$('body').click(function(){
    clicks ++;
    console.log(clicks);
});

switch(clicks){
       case 1:
       $('#contentlist1').fadeIn(50);
       break; 
       case 2:
       $('#contentlist2').fadeIn(50);
       break;   
       case 3:
       console.log("this is 3");
       break;           
       case 4:
       $('#contentlist4').fadeIn(50);
       break;   
       };
```

What I want to do is let elements fade in one after each other on each subsequent click, like powerpoint bulletpoint animations, but it isn't working.

I've changed the fadeIn to console.log('message') etc. to see if it was the fadein that's broken, but I think the switch doesn't work, not the fade. (the elements are already faded out, so the fade should work properly).

What's wrong with this code? I've looked at some sources and it shouldn't be because 'clicks' is an integer value.

Comment: Your `switch` only ever runs once with the value of `0`.  When you click, you are changing `change`, but never re-running the `switch` statement.

Comment: @RocketHazmat thanks for the quick answer! That's actually quite logical... Would putting my switch inside the 'body.click...' -function help?

Comment: Why not give it a try? :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat aight, it works now... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your switch statement should be inside the `click` function and you should check when `clicks` is more than the `max` cases,

```
var clicks = 0;

$('body').click(function() {
    if(++clicks > 4) clicks = 1;

    switch (clicks) {
        case 1:
            $('#contentlist1').fadeIn(50);
            break;
        case 2:
            $('#contentlist2').fadeIn(50);
            break;
        case 3:
            console.log("this is 3");
            break;
        case 4:
            $('#contentlist4').fadeIn(50);
            break;
    };
    console.log(clicks);
});
```

Comment: Problem solved! :D thanks for the quick responses. still a rookie mistake though, but I guess we all gotta learn at some point